# What is this esxi process net-lacp?

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi

I was looking at esxtop on my 5.5 host and I see this process net-lacp running. I'm using standard vswitches, I'm diagnosing network performance issues and I wonder if its related to this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the LACP process for [VMware vSphere Distributed Switches](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2051826).

It is not the cause of your network woes.

Comment: But I'm not licensed for vDS nor am I using any.

Comment: @thedave That doesn't matter. It's the same ESXi regardless of licensing level.

Comment: LACP isn't just used for distributed switches.  Link Aggregation Control Protocl is used for NIC teaming/failover, which this process monitors/manages as well if I'm not mistaken. NIC teaming is a standard feature of ESX which explains why this process would be running on your installation.  Again though, this is most likely not the cause of your network issue.

Comment: It ended up being a driver issue [link]http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/topIssuesDisplay/?sp4ts.oid=5177957&spf_p.tpst=psiContentDisplay&spf_p.prp_psiContentDisplay=wsrp-navigationalState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c04172041-1%257CdocLocale%253Den_US&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken

Comment: @thedave That's a pretty terrible driver bug.